# How to write the result of a function in a slice

Tags: string, go, slice

In the example, everything works fine. But they do not use the variable a and immediately display it https://play.golang.org/p/O0XwtQJRej

But I have a problem:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "fulltext"
    var slice []string
    slice = strings.Split(str , "")

    fmt.Printf("anwer: ", slice)
}
```

Whence in the answer there are superfluous characters, for example

> %! (EXTRA [] string =

P.S. I know that I need to use append to add elements to the slice, but now I do not understand how to apply append here.

UP:
Now I have the answer:

> anwer: %!(EXTRA []string=[f u l l t e x t])

But I need just:

> [f u l l t e x t]

But I do not understand how I should change my code?

Comment: (Note the `%q` in the screen dump, and refer to the reference [(godoc.org?)](https://godoc.org/fmt) for `fmt.Printf()`.)

Comment: @greybeard Yes, I saw these characters, but in my code they are missing

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? what do you mean by `I do not understand how to apply append here`. `Split` func returns the slice.

Comment: @jeevatkm  Thank you! I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give to printf the expected format, in most cases, `%v` is fine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "fulltext"
    var slice []string
    slice = strings.Split(str, "")

    fmt.Printf("anwer: %v", slice)
}
```

see https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the assignment of the return value of `strings.Split()` to the local variable `slice`, which is totally fine.

The problem is that you used [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) which expects a format string, and based on that format string it formats / substitutes expected parameters. Since your format string does not contain any verbs, that `fmt.Printf()` call expects no parameters, yet you pass it one, so it signals this with those extra characters (kind of error string).

Provide a valid format string where you indicate you will supply 1 parameter, a slice:

```
fmt.Printf("answer: %v", slice)
```

With this, the output is:

```
answer: [f u l l t e x t]
```

Or alternatively use [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println), which does not expect a format string:

```
fmt.Println("answer:", slice)
```

(Note that there is no space after the colon, as `fmt.Println()` adds a space between 2 values if one of them is of type `string`).

Output is the same. Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CoetMQfDpE).

Staying with `fmt.Printf()`, when the parameter involves `string` values, the `%q` verb is often more useful, as that will print quoted string values, much easier to spot certain mistakes (e.g. invisible characters, or if a `string` contains spaces, it will become obvious):

```
fmt.Printf("answer: %q\n", slice)
```

Output of this (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EoFIjCPMfm)):

```
answer: ["f" "u" "l" "l" "t" "e" "x" "t"]
```

If you'd wanted to append the result of a function call, this is how it could look like:

```
slice := []string{"initial", "content"}
slice = append(slice, strings.Split(str, "")...)

fmt.Printf("answer: %q\n", slice)
```

And now the output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mul1SfLuLY)):

```
answer: ["initial" "content" "f" "u" "l" "l" "t" "e" "x" "t"]
```